# How to have the partial Lowercase Decoding the URL?

Tags: java, url, java-8, decoding

I have encoded link. After the decoding

```
String decodedURL = URLDecoder.decode(encodedLink, "UTF-8");
String delims = "[u, &]";
String[] splittedURL = decodedURL.split(delims);
String resultURL = splittedURL[1].substring(1);
```

I get next link:

```
http://example.com?I=vNjWAwAAAABfva85AgAAAABR%2Fv%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FBGNhdnMA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8%3D
```

But in this part:

```
%2Fv%2F%2F%2FwD%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FBGNhdnMA%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F8%3D
```

I need to have only "F" and "D" letters in Lowercase:
F -> f,
D -> d.
Is it possible to perform decoding after which this letters will be in Lowercase without splitting the decoded link and make necessary letters

```
.toLowerCase();
```

?

Comment: Why do you have to convert them to lower case when URL percent-encoding is NOT case sensitive?

Comment: I have an auto test which compares two links using comparator. First link has part with "%2f%" and second decoded link has "%2F%". In such case test fails.

Comment: @KirylParkhomenka in that case you can use equalsIgnoreCase() method

Comment: equalsIgnoreCase() is not a good fit in my case, because two links are compared in framework's comparator.